# Как перевести бинарный код в десятичный?

Tags: java

Задача:

> Дано натуральное число m. Найти такое натуральное n, что двоичная запись n получается из двоичной записи t изменением порядка цифр на обратный (t задано в десятичной системе, и n надо также получить в десятичной системе, например, для t=6 получается n=3).

Суть вот в чем, не знаю, как вернуть полученный обратный код числа в десятичный вид.
Пример того, что я уже сделал:

Решено, готовый код, пусть и не самый лучший но все же:

```
    import java.io.*;

public class Binary {
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{
        System.out.println("Введите  число");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s = br.readLine();
        myRev(s);
    }

    public static void myRev (String s){
        try {
            int k = Integer.parseInt(s);
            if(k<0) {System.out.println("Число "+s+" не натуральное"); System.exit(1);}
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Число "+s+" не натуральное"); System.exit(1);}

            System.out.print("Число:" + s + "\n");
            int f = Integer.parseInt(s);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            do {
                sb.append(f % 2);
                f = f / 2;
            } while (f != 0);
            String S = new String (sb.reverse());            
            int result = 0;
            for (int i=0; i<S.length (); i++){
                result += Math.pow(2, i) * (S.charAt(i) == '1'?1:0);
            }

        System.out.println("В 2-ном виде: " + sb + "\n");
        System.out.println("Обратный код: " + sb.reverse());
        System.out.println("Ответ : " + result);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простейший вариант:

```
public static int bin2dec(String binNumber) {
    int result = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < binNumber.length(); i++) {
        result += Math.pow(2, i) * (binNumber.charAt(i) == '1' ? 1 : 0);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Кстати, а самый простой вариант решения всей задачи мог бы быть основан на этом выражении:

```
new BigInteger(
    new StringBuilder(
        new BigInteger(decString).toString(2)
    ).reverse().toString(), 2
).toString();
```

Comment: Не самый лучший вариант использовать степень, для более высокой производительности лучше использовать операцию сдвига (<< и >>), и побитовую операцию "или" (|).

Comment: на то он и простейший :)

Comment: Извините за глупый вопрос..(ноя ведь все таки только учусь)...второй метод что вы показали я заметил намного удобней того что я написал, но мой Bluej чего то его не принимает((посоветуйте что не так

Comment: @Дмитрий Тюрин, а что значит "не принимает" - какие ошибки? Проблемы с компиляцией? Учтите, что второй пример - лишь кусочек кода, выполняющий основную работу и оставляющий за вами валидацию входящих данных.

Comment: А все, извиняюсь, как говорится, учусь на ошибках. )
Все заработало, готовый код сейчас добавлю. ) Большое спасибо вам, yozh, без вас бы не справился. )))

Answer (score 1):

Простейший вариант:

```
public static int bin2dec(String binNumber) {

    return Integer.parseInt( binNumber, 2);
}
```